# How to remove all TEXT/Numbers between ( and ) in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I've been bashing my brains out trying to figure out how to remove text/numbers between the ( and ) in a column within my sqlite3 db. I've tried rtrim, ltrim, substr() all to no avail. Any expert sqlite3 guru care to help me? I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might *partially* depend on your SQLite implementation.  From [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If a user-defined function named "regexp" is added at run-time, that function will be called in order to implement the REGEXP operator.

If your implementation *does* have a `REGEXP` defined, then it should be as simple as a regex of "`(.*?)\(.*?\)(.*)`", returning only groups 1 and 2 to ignore what's inside the parentheses.

This approach is not portable because possibly most SQLite implementations do not have `REGEXP` defined.

Someone at [this forum](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/38836) recently went through a long thread asking for almost the same thing, and he didn't have any luck.  To the best of my knowledge, there's no built-in functionality to do this.

His final answer in there was to trim off a constant number of characters, because all the data was uniformly ending in '@xyz.com' -- if your data is similarly uniform, you could just trim off the leading and trailing X and Y characters.

In fact, back in *2003*, [someone made a patch for `charindex` support](http://osdir.com/ml/db.sqlite.general/2003-11/msg00061.html), but for some reason it apparently was never added into the trunk.  Someone else made [a similar patch with more functionality](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg22630.html), but this requires you to load an external shared library -- again, not *exactly* portable.

That last one might be your best option -- writing a shared library in C, and [`LOADing` it from SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions).   Or you could just implement the string modification in whichever language you're using SQLite :)